# How do I affirm the existance of a list of keys in a mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a database table containing a 'key' field which holds a system generated key.

```
| id | key                 | etc.
|====|=====================|================= 
|  1 | osi32i4kjwlqe       |
|----|---------------------|-----------------
|  2 | klwjeklj1343k       |
|----|---------------------|-----------------
|  3 | dfk32ld32ll23       |
|----|---------------------|----------------
|  4 | lk3jkl3j42lk4       |
--------------------------------------------
```

In addition, I have a list of keys:

```
{'osi32i4kjwlqe','ksadalala12','klwjeklj1343k','dfk32ld32ll23','lk3jkl3j42lk4','askalksl56'}
```

Note, that some of the keys on the list exist in the database, and others do not.

I would like, if I can, to run an efficient query that will go through the list, and affirm the existence of the key in the database.

ie: if the key exists, do nothing. if it doesn't, insert a fresh row with this key.

Does anybody know of an efficient way to do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that your key column is declared with `UNIQUE`. If so, just loop and use

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table ...
```

for each of your keys from JSON array. If not, well, make so as I think this is what you want to accomplish anyway :)

Comment: It should be added the above assumes there's a `unique` constraint on the `key` column.

Comment: True, assumption that column named `key` is UNIQUE is unjustified. Corrected.